# How can I loop till certain range inside the list?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of 5000 words.

`words=['asd','bsd',.........,'dbn']`

I am trying to make the possible combinations of the words

```
comb = combinations(words,2)
for i in list(comb): 
  b=''.join(i)
  print(b)
```

How can I run the loop for the first 100 words combinations?

Comment: What exactly is `comb`? The output of `itertools.combinations`?

Comment: How many words you are trying to combine? Two or more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) from the `itertools` module. The following will display the first 100 combinations of length 2:

```
from itertools import combinations, islice

for c in islice(combinations(words, 2), 100):
    print(c)
```

Note that both functions return lazy generators, so that not all combinations have to be generated first (which is what happens once you call `list(comb...)`).

Answer (score 0):

There is this great module called [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), which most probably has what you need. Example from the permutations function:

```
# permutations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC
# permutations(range(3)) --> 012 021 102 120 201 210
```